# Символ ' в SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Делаю такой SQLite запрос:

```
INSERT INTO events (
  id, Date_Fixing, Date_Generation, Source, Event_Type, Event, Alert, Original_Event_Text
)
VALUES (
  NULL,
  'пт авг. 12 19:26:53 2016',
  'пт авг. 12 19:26:53 2016',
  '1',
  '4',
  'Событие НСД: РМО01. Перебор пароля пользователя: v_ivanov',
  '1',
  '<85>login[5077]: TOO MANY LOGIN TRIES (3) on '/dev/tty1' FOR 'v_ivanov' '
);
```

Выводит такую ошибку:
Error: near line 1: near "' FOR '": syntax error

Чем можно ли как то выполнить данный запрос вместе с символами ''?

Comment: а пробовали использовать " " или \' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дублируйте кавычки.

```
INSERT INTO events (
  id, Date_Fixing, Date_Generation, Source, Event_Type, Event, Alert, Original_Event_Text
) 
VALUES (
  NULL,
  'пт авг. 12 19:26:53 2016',
  'пт авг. 12 19:26:53 2016',
  '1',
  '4',
  'Событие НСД: РМО01. Перебор пароля пользователя: v_ivanov',
  '1',
  '<85>login[5077]: TOO MANY LOGIN TRIES (3) on ''/dev/tty1'' FOR ''v_ivanov'' '
);
```

[A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two single quotes in a row](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)